# PhpStorm How to open the folder containing files on remote host

Tags: phpstorm

I'm so tired of opening each folder to get where I need to go

Go to Folder Local: Ctrl + Shift + N -> Open File > Select Opened File

[image]

Go to Folder Remote Host: ????
Is there a way to find the folder containing the file in the fastest way on the remote host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Go to Folder Remote Host: ???? Is there a way to find the folder containing the file in the fastest way on the remote host?

If you are asking: "I have some folder name and want to type/paste it somewhere and the IDE should select that folder in the Remote Host panel"... then the answer is No.

---

But if you want to navigate from a local location to a corresponding remote place -- then Yes.

This works for the currently opened/active file in the Editor .. or any folder or file currently selected in the Project View panel (should also work from other places where files are listed).

It's a 2-step shortcut... and the first part is already there, on your screenshot:

[image]

<kbd>Alt+F1</kbd> (which is a shortcut for `Navigate | Select In...`). Then just select `Remote Host` (<kbd>3</kbd>) in the popup. So the full shortcut is <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>.

For example: me invoking the first part of the shortcut on a `themes` folder selected in the Project View panel.

[image]

**NOTES:**

1. It is **required** that you have a Deployment entry configured in your IDE and it should be **selected as Default**. The "Remote Host" option will be unavailable if you have no Default deployment entry.
2. Obviously, the deployment entry must be configured properly (the path mappings). I mean -- you should be able to upload/download files with no issues.
3. If there is no active connection to the remote host yet, then the action will fail mid way (will stop after showing the Remote Host panel and establishing the connection). In such a case just repeat the shortcut again.

   The action will work just fine if the Remote Host panel is already visible and there is an active connection to the remote host.

A few Help Pages links:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#navigate_in_project_view
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tutorial-deployment-in-product.html#mapping-tab

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Very complete and detailed answer
Thank you so much for this
It saved me a lot of time.
Thank you again